# apt-get dist upgrade results in Error 403 Virus found

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, malware

I'm behind a corporate firewall, but I *thought* that I got the security team to open up the update sites so that I could update Ubuntu.

However now I'm getting a VirusFound error??

```
username@computer:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libandroid-properties1 libsctp1 lksctp-tools
The following packages will be upgraded:
  icedtea-7-jre-jamvm liboxideqt-qmlplugin liboxideqtcore0 liboxideqtquick0
  openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless oxideqt-codecs
8 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 86.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 6,533 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libsctp1 i386 1.0.15+dfsg-1 [9,358 B]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main openjdk-7-jdk i386 7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  403  VirusFound [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main openjdk-7-jre i386 7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [168 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main icedtea-7-jre-jamvm i386 7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [425 kB]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main openjdk-7-jdk i386 7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  403  VirusFound [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
```

I killed the operation with `ctrl-c` after this line so nothing else to show.

Does anyone know what that means?  Could it have something to do with the firewall software?

Comment: This must be some corporate firewall thing.

Comment: @Pilot6 I think you're right. Is it possible that the message is not an error message from the actual command, but rather inserted by the firewall software?

Comment: This is a reject message from the firewall. It blocks `jdk` or something.

Comment: @geneorama: Looks like it...

Comment: I notified our security team. It's annoying that McAfee communicates its block with an ambiguous "VirusFound" message, which isn't even an actual error message but rather it's a code of some sort that suggests a message that  a virus was found. Of course since there's no information about how or why they came to this conclusion, I can't ask for a remedy like "please unblock this" (if it's even blocked). Thanks for your helpful comments though, helps me confirm that it's not an Ubuntu issue.

Comment: This is a corporate firewall thing, but I don't see why it's "off topic". The error still comes through on the apt-get command.